# npm ERR! Cache dir is required

Tags: node.js, npm

When running npm install command, I kept getting "npm ERR! Cache dir is required" error.

```
npm install -g create-react-app

npm ERR! Cache dir is required
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

---

Update: The error disappeared without doing anything

Comment: What is the output of `npm cache verify` ?

Comment: The output is: Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache)